# How to work with less combinations of variables in R combn function?

Tags: r, list, combinations

I'm creating a loop with combn function in R. My goal is to obtain every combination of 133 variables characters from 2 until 133 combinations from a vector with the names. However, when I start my code, the routine stop and gives me the following statment: "Error: Unable to allocate vector of size 2.4Gb". It happens when the routine starts with five combinations.

There is a condition to reduce the amount of combination that would help to turn the list smaller. I'm desire to keep just combinations that have the following string: "var_pib_nsa_interanual"

Below it's my code:

```
gc() #garbage collection - clear memory.
memory.limit (9999999999) # increase the memory size.

nome_series <- c("x.consu_energia_brasil_total","x.massa_sal_ampl","x.ibc_br","x.selic_aa","x.base_monetaria","x.ipca_adm_var","x.ipca_livre_var","x.ipca_alim_domic_var","x.cambio_real_efet_ipca","x.tx_media_juros_pf_total","x.utiliza_capac_ocio_fgv","x.pib_mensal","x.ipca_cheio_var_nsa","x.consu_energia_industr","x.consu_energia_residencia","x.consu_energia_comercial","x.economic_conditions","x.house_index,"x.sales_vehicles","x.sales_credit","x.usa_economic","x.Anfavea_Producao_de_automoveis_e_comerciais_leves","x.Anfavea_Producao_de_caminhoes_e_onibus","x.Fenabrave_Licenciamento_de_veiculos_novos","x.Funcex_Exportacao_total","x.Funcex_Exportacao_de_manufaturados","x.Funcex_Importacao_total","x.IAB_Producao_de_aco_bruto","x.capacity_utilization","x.exportssurvey","x.Abraciclo_Producao_de_motocicletas","x.industrial_production","x.manu_production","x.civil","x.prod_agro","x.civil_price","x.services","x.inflation","x.ABAL_Producao_de_aluminio_primario","x.exchangerate","x.consumer_survey","x.Receita_Federal_Arrecadacao_de_IPI","x.Receita_Federal_Arrecadacao_de_IR","x.Receita_Federal_Arrecadacao_IOF","x.BNDES_COM","x.BNDES_TOTAL","x.businesssurvey","x.igp_m_var_mensal","x.interestrate2","x.Funcex_Importacao_de_materias_primas","x.alcool","x.carne_bovina","x.carne_suina","x.carnes_aves","x.celulose","x.minerio_ferro",...)                                       

num_elementos <- 1:5
combinacoes_possiveis <- list()
comb <- list()


for (i in 2:length(num_elementos)) {
    combinacoes_possiveis[[i]] <- combn(nome_series,
                                        num_elementos[i],
                                        simplify = FALSE
                                        )
    
     comb[[i]] <- Filter(function(x){"var_pib_nsa_interanual" %in% x}, 
                    combinacoes_possiveis[[i]]
                    )
     
     combinacoes_possiveis[[i]] <- NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Iterators

Generally speaking when you are dealing with memory problems, iterators are a great option for getting around this hardware limitation.

For example, the package `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) and the package `arrangements` offer combinatorial iterators. Instead of generating everything up front and then filtering, you would generate one combination at a time and carry out your check. Something like:

```r
library(RcppAlgos)
iter <- comboIter(nome_series, num_elementos[i])
res <- iter@nextIter()

while (!is.null(res)) {
    ## Your check here as well as what you
    ## want to do with the current combination
    ## if the check is successful
    ## .
    ## .
    ## .

    res <- iter@nextIter()
}
```

And with the package `arrangements` we have:

```r
library(arrangements)
iter <- icombinations(nome_series, num_elementos[i])
res <- iter$getnext()

while (!is.null(res)) {
    ## Same as above
    res <- iter$getnext()
}
```

### Better Solution

A better solution is to think a little harder about your actual problem. It looks like you only want combinations that contain a certain value. In these instances, simply leave this value out and generate all combinations of *n - 1* choose *m - 1*, then tack on your value of choice. Remember, with combinations, order doesn't matter, so `c(1, 2, 3)` is equivalent to `c(2, 1, 3)`.

Below is a small example. Let's say we want only combinations of 5 choose 3 where 2 is in the combination. Using the method outlined by the OP, we have:

```r
Filter(\(x) 2 %in% x, combn(5, 3, simplify = FALSE))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2 5
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 2 3 4
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 2 3 5
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 2 4 5
```

Now, using the method outlined above, we have:

```r
## If the output doesn't matter, below is a very simple method
combn(c(1, 3, 4, 5), 2, \(x) c(x, 2))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    3    3    4
# [2,]    3    4    5    4    5    5
# [3,]    2    2    2    2    2    2

## Or using rbind
rbind(2, combn(c(1, 3, 4, 5), 2))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2
# [2,]    1    1    1    3    3    4
# [3,]    3    4    5    4    5    5

## Or if the output really needs to be a list
combn(c(1, 3, 4, 5), 2, \(x) c(x, 2), simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 4 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 5 2
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 3 4 2
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 3 5 2
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 4 5 2
```

Of course, if memory is still an issue, we could use iterators along with this approach. In fact, `RcppAlgos::comboIter` offers a `FUN` argument similar to `combn` which allows you to get the desired result while also keeping memory low:

```r
iter <- comboIter(c(1, 3, 4, 5), 2, FUN = \(x) c(x, 2))
iter@nextIter()
# [1] 1 3 2

## Get more than one at a time
iter@nextNIter(2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 4 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 5 2

## Get the remaining combinations
iter@nextRemaining()
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 4 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 5 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 4 5 2
```

You can also make use of the `FUN.VALUE` argument to get simplified output.

```r
iter <- comboIter(c(1, 3, 4, 5), 2, FUN = \(x) c(x, 2),
                  FUN.VALUE = c(1, 2, 3))
iter@nextNIter(3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    2
# [2,]    1    4    2
# [3,]    1    5    2
```

Comment: I didn't resolve my problem yet, but it gives me an good alternative.